# Difference between <g:actionSubmit> and <g:submittButton>

Tags: grails

I am very new to grails. I have created a form. Where the action is ... action:"save".
at the bottom of my form, I have used `<g:actionSubmitt value="SAVE"/>`. Notice here I have used value="SAVE" in capitalize and I got a 404. But I never faced this kind of problem in Spring. My query is, So I have to maintain the exact word that I have used in action: "save" and inside the value="save". And why on earth where I should use `<g:submitButton>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<g:actionSubmitt value="SAVE"/>` lets you specify which action from the controller should be invoked. So if your form needs several different actions, like `save` and `delete`, you can use this tag. This also explains your 404 - you probably don't have a `SAVE` controller.

http://docs.grails.org/3.1.1/ref/Tags/actionSubmit.html

`<g:submitButton>` just adds a submit button with a name but without further functionality. So if you add several submit button, they will all invoke the same controller which you've specified in your `<form>` tag.

http://docs.grails.org/3.1.1/ref/Tags/submitButton.html